# Is it possible to reduce the number of identical calls in a v-for?

Tags: vue.js

The following code snippet shows an extreme example where the exact same method is being called multiple times.  Is there a way to condense this so it doesn't explicitly get called N-number of times?

```
<someTag v-for="data in getData" :key="generateKey(data)-key" class="generateKey(data)" :id="generateKey(data)">
 <p>{{ data.someProperty }}, {{ data.someOtherProperty }}</p>
</someTag>
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're trying to address?

Comment: Avoiding duplicate calls in a v-for which could be computationally heavy. This is an extreme example, but simply demonstrates the problem

Comment: one option might be to have an object where the key is data and the generated key is the value. You call the function once and it sets the value and the others use computed/getters to return the corresponding value

Comment: So in other words, a wrapper around the existing data?  I believe that would work, but I was really hoping there'd be some baked in syntax which did the manual creation of wrappers for you. Still sounds like the best idea at the moment though

Comment: Alternatively, `getData` could generate the key for the data and add the key as a property to it. Without seeing `getData` and the data structure, it'd be difficult to tell you exactly how to do so.

Comment: You could have `computed` property that outflux a transformed `getData` with fields for `key class and id` binding for each of the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
...
computed: {
  mappedData () {
    return this.getData.map(d => {
      d.key = generateKey(d)
      return d
    })
  }
}
```

and

```
<someTag v-for="data in mappedData" :key="`${data.key}-key`" :class="data.key" :id="data.key">
 <p>{{ data.someProperty }}, {{ data.someOtherProperty }}</p>
</someTag>
```

66% less generateKey calls in O(n)